# What is the process to create tables in PostgreSQL for a specific schema and table owner

Tags: postgresql, ubuntu-20.04

I am new to Postgres having come from an Oracle background.

I am using pgAdmin4 where I have created a database called **my_db** as well as a schema called **admin_schema**.

What are the steps to ensure that all new tables created within the **my_db** database belong to the schema **admin_schema** and table owner **admin_owner**, which I am unsure how to create?

I basically do not want the tables I create belonging to the schemaname PUBLIC and tableowner POSTGRES.

### Updated

To answer queries below:

- I am using pgAdmin4 within Ubuntu 20.04 and I assume I am logging in as user postgres
- I only have one server where the username is postgres
- I currently do not have a user or role called admin_owner as unsure how to create this?
- Unsure how to start pgAdmin so that it uses the user: admin_owner?
- I basically want all my tables to be owned by admin_owner under the schema of admin_schema within the database my_db

Comment: Are you logging in as `postgres` to create these tables?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "ensure"? Do you just want this become the default for tables created with `CREATE TABLE` (for which users)? Or deny arbitrary users the permission to create any other tables at all?

Comment: You could certainly drop the `public` schema if you want to prevent it from being used :-)

Comment: did you already create the role `admin_owner` with a password. is that role permitted to create schemas & tables?

Comment: Have updated my main post to cover off your questions above.

Comment: so i didn't understand are you able to login to you postgresql server using PGAdmin or not? are you able to login using shell?

Comment: @eshirvana - I am able to login into both pgAdmin as well as the psql shell.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I currently do not have a user or role called admin_owner as unsure how to create this

To [create](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-createuser.html) a user, log in as the superuser (`postgres`)  then run:

```
create user admin_owner with password '******';
```

> I basically want all my tables to be owned by admin_owner under the schema of admin_schema within the database my_db

After you have created the user, create [the schema](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/ddl-schemas.html):

```
create schema admin_schema 
   authorization admin_user; --<< this makes admin_user the owner of the schema.
```

If you don't want to prefix the every table reference with the schema name, change the [search path](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/ddl-schemas.html#DDL-SCHEMAS-PATH) for the admin user:

```
alter user admin_user  
   set search_path = admin_schema;
```

> Unsure how to start pgAdmin so that it uses the user: admin_owner

Create a new connection in pgAdmin (confusingly called "Server") specify `admin_user` as the user name and provide the password you specified when you created the user.

---

Depending on how you configured your Postgres server, you might need to adjust [pg_hba.conf](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/auth-pg-hba-conf.html) to allow remote password connections.

Answer (score 0):

As an Oracle user, you are naturally confused about schemas. Schemas are different from users. The only connection is that schemas (like all other database objects) have an owner. In particular, tables cannot belong to a schema, they can be (logically) located in a schema.

To have a table belong to a certain user, log into the database as that user and create the table. An object belongs to the user that created it.

To put the tables in a certain schema, qualify the table name with the schema:

```
CREATE TABLE admin_schema.table (...);
```

Comment: As an alternative, if you created the table when logger in as a different owner you can change to table's owner with: ALTER TABLE [schema_name.]table_name OWNER TO another_username;